# Adding another background image to an element that already has an inline background image

Tags: html, css, background-image

I'm facing a problem where a background image is set inline in the HTML (because it's a dynamic image src that comes from the database) but I still want to add a semi-transparent gradient **on top** of the existing background image.

Is this at all possible without using JS?

```css
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, .6), rgba(0, 0, 0, .2)); /* I need this to be added **on top** of the existing background image */
}
```

```html
<div style="background-image: url(//lorempixel.com/1920/1080/nature/)"></div>
```

Comment: a workaround would be to have another `div` just inside this `div` and give the gradient background to that div, so it will be above the original background-image

Comment: I'm more or less using that fallback now, but instead of nested div:s I'm using `:before`. It works, but using multiple backgrounds felt like a cleaner solution imo. Also, the `:before` trick together with `display table-cell` doesn't work correctly in IE(9 or 10). Was hoping this would fix that too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't add another `background-image` via CSS if there is one being set via inline styles. But you can use a pseudo-element and place it on top of the `div`.

**Note:** As pointed out in comments by Mike, using a `:before` element is much better than using the `:after` element because the `:after` gets placed on top of everything else and would need a lot of `z-index` settings to the other elements to overcome it (which, could become tedious). In addition to this setting `pointer-events:none` on the pseudo-element would also help.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
div:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, .6), rgba(0, 0, 0, .2));
  pointer-events: none;
}
div * {
  position: relative;
}
a, p, span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-image: url(//lorempixel.com/1920/1080/nature/)">
  <a href='#'>Some link for hit test</a>
  <p>Some paragraph to test the color being affected by gradient on top or not</p>
  <span>Some span to test the color being affected by gradient on top or not</span>
</div>
```

---

Multiple background images can be added to a single element using CSS but like other properties, the declarations are not additive and hence both the image and the gradient should either be set via CSS (or) by the back-end.

Below is a sample snippet where both the gradient and the image are set inline. You could store entire value as a string in DB (or) append it while setting the inline style (using JS or back-end program).

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
a, p, span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-image: url(//lorempixel.com/1920/1080/nature/), linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, .6), rgba(0, 0, 0, .2))">
  <a href='#'>Some link for hit test</a>
  <p>Some paragraph to test the color being affected by gradient on top or not</p>
  <span>Some span to test the color being affected by gradient on top or not</span>
</div>
```

Comment: perhaps `:before` would work better as `after` would block all interactions to the contents of the div. or you could manage it using `z-index`

Comment: @Mike: We could ofcourse set `pointer-events: none` on the `:after` to avoid it from affecting the interactions with the layer below.

Comment: @Mike: You got a very valid point about the `:before`. Initially I didn't realize that the gradient on `:after` would affect the other elements inside the element with the background also. Thanks for that. I have updated the answer :)

Comment: Thanks, I'm already using this trick. I mentioned this above but yea, it works fine, but using multiple backgrounds felt like a cleaner solution imo. Also, the `:before` trick together with `display table-cell` doesn't work correctly in IE(9 or 10). Was hoping this would fix that too.

Comment: I guess in the future we could use `<div data-image="//lorempixel...">...` and then `div {background-image: linear-gradient(...), attr(data-image url)`. No support yet though :/

Comment: @powerbuoy Unfortunately you can't *add* to an existing background image. Either both have to be set via CSS or via JS as value for a single property. CSS `attr` has very little support. If you want to do this without using a pseudo then the best approach would be to set the image + gradient via JS (or whatever backend program).

Comment: `attr` has fine support, but not for the `type-or-unit` property (https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values/#typedef-type-or-unit). The problem I'm experiencing in IE can be seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/ry9tcpjf/ - the `:before` element doesn't cover the parent for some reason.

Comment: @powerbuoy I meant the `attr` as value for a property other than `content`. You can see the browser support [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/attr). I checked your fiddle with IE and can see the problem. I will try to debug it but in the meantime have a look at the second option in my answer. It might be better to set both inline using JS or backend program.

Comment: Ah ok :) Yes I may resort to JS, or I may let IE9-11 look a bit weird here... I posted a new question for my... new question :P If you come up with anything: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36623162/absolutely-positioned-pseudo-element-inside-table-cell-does-not-cover-parent-in