# Absolutely positioned pseudo element inside table cell does not cover parent in IE9/10

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a nested div setup displayed as table and table-cell, where each cell has an absolutely positioned `:before` element that covers the entire cell. This works fine everywhere except in IE9, 10 and 11 where the before element only covers the *content* part of the cell.

```css
div.wrap {
  display: table;
}

div.wrap > div {
  background: green;
  display: table-cell;
  position: relative;
}

div.wrap > div:before {
  background: red;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

div.wrap > div > * {
  position: relative; /* render on top of overlay */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div>
    <h2>
      Content number 1
    </h2>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>
      Content number 2
    </h2>
    <p>
      With more content
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Anyone know if this can be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I ended up solving it was to simply give the `:before` element a ridiculous `min-height` (in my case 2000px but depends on your use case) along with `overflow: hidden` on the table-cell.